# How to use "UPDATE Products SET Price = Price + 50 WHERE ProductID = 1" this kind of SQlite statement in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to  update the a specific row of the Column.I tried to use the statement to set my value using 'db.update()'.But I cant.Is there any method which I can use to use the statement of the title to set the value of a specific row of a column?

Comment: whats the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the documentation explicitly mentions that the recommended and proper way to update a table is the method `update()`, your requirement can only be done with `execSQL()`.

Either with [`execSQL(String sql)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#execSQL(java.lang.String)):

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE Products SET Price = Price + 50 WHERE ProductID = 1");
```

or with [`execSQL (String sql, Object[] bindArgs)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#execSQL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object/%5B/%5D)):

```
db.execSQL(
    "UPDATE Products SET Price = Price + ? WHERE ProductID = ?",
    new String[] {"50", "1"}
);
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked.But will I face any issue for this kind of approach as it is not recommended in documentation?

Comment: With `execSQL()` you can execute any valid sql statement so you will not face any issue. The recommendation is to use the methods update(), insert() and delete() for updates, insertions and deletions. But your requirement obviously can't be done with the method update() since the current value of the column is needed which can't be supplied to a ContentValues object.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you. db.update() with ContentValues () is more safe updating method. Check this one.

```
     int i = 50;
     Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from Products where ProductId = 1 LIMIT 1");
      if(res.getCount() > 0){
            i += Integer.parseInt(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("Price")));
        }
    
     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
     values.put("Price", i.toString());
     db.update("Products",values,"ProductId = ?",new String[]{"1"});
```

I am not sure but I think that the problem may be setting Price column type as text. If so, change it integer.

Comment: Check this one.

Answer (score 0):

To update your sql db use `db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, where, whereArgs);` You can read about [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29).The use case can look like this:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("column_name", "updated value");

db.update("table_name", cv, "column_id" +  "=?",new String[]{"primary_id"});
```

Comment: The requirement is to **increase** the column Price by 50 and not to set it to 50.

Comment: I only explained how to use dp.update(), not set ist to 50. what he puts in is up to him.

Comment: The OP know how to use update(): *I tried to use the statement to set my value using 'db.update()'.But I cant* but the requirement can not be done with update().

Comment: maybe your right, but thats the problem when the error is "But I cant". It can be misleading..

Comment: @forpas was right.But I admit my question  was a bit misleading.Next time I'll try to be more precise.Thanks brother.

Answer (score 0):

`update()` only works with `ContentValues` which is a wrapper for SQL variable binding. You can only bind values, not expressions like `Price + 50`.

To use an expression like that, use `execSQL()` with the raw SQL string you already have.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

`db.execSQL( "UPDATE Products SET Price = ? WHERE ProductID = ?", new String[] {Price+50 , "1"} );`

Comment: Is `Price+50` a String?

Comment: "**Price**" is any integer value which is **incremented by 50**

Comment: Is it? If so how can you store it in an array of strings?